# Цикличное листание фрагментов Android. ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Ребят, пишу приложение на Android. Расписание занятий для универа. Имеется база данных SQLite с самим расписанием на каждый день(2 учебные недели). После Start Screen'a открывается расписание на текущий день и нужно при свайпе перейти на следующий или предыдущий.
Так вот, как сделать чтобы при достижении пятницы, при следующем свайпе вправо открывался снова понедельник ? Пробовал Swipe Views с FragmentPagerAdpter, но там нужно указывать конкретное кол-во страниц, и в итоге перелистывание заканчивается. Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать, куда нужно копать и какой материал прочитать.

Comment: а если поставить слушатель на свайп и делать проверку , в случае если пятница подгружать понедельник

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант решения могу предложить назначить слушателя для ViewPager:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (curr == 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Улучшил этот вариант, добавил 2 страницы после пятницы и перед понедельником для подгрузки, и если открывается эта страница, перекидывает уже на  оригинальный день, для красивой анимации.

```
@Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int current = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (current == 6 ) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);    // Переход после пятницы, на оригинальный понедельник
                } else if (current == 0) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(5, false);    
                }
        }
    }});

     @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        int CurrentDay = position;
        if (position == 0) {
            return CardViewActivity.newInstance(2);   //Подгрузка пятницы перед понедельником
        } else {
            return CardViewActivity.newInstance(position - 3);  
        }
    }
```